# Mockito - How do I mock a method that recieves param - (Object... o)

Tags: java, mockito

How do I mock a method that receives param - (Object... o)?
for instance I have the following method

```
Obj getByIds(String... ids);
```

I want something like

```
doReturn(...).when(myProxy).getByIds(any(String[].class));
```

or

```
doReturn(...).when(myProxy).getByIds(any(String.class));
```

But they both fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try
`doReturn(...).when(myProxy).getByIds((String) anyVarargs())`

Answer (score 2):

```
doReturn(...).when(myProxy).getByIds(Matchers.<String>anyVararg())
```

should work, see [here](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Matchers.html#anyVararg())